# How to force resource compiler on each compile?

Tags: delphi, configuration, embedded-resource

Is there a project/compiler/linker-setting that can force brcc32.exe to run on some or all `.rc` files included into the project? By default only `.rc` files that have changed get re-compiled, but not when any files included by the `.rc` are. For now we manually delete the `.res` file(s) to force a re-compile.

**Update:** inspired by the accepted answer, I wrote this: https://gist.github.com/2868141

Comment: I'm working on projects in version 6, 7 and XE2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't used Delphi for years, but as far as I remember you can define pre-build events, can't you? You could [touch](http://www.helge.mynetcologne.de/touch/index.htm) all the rc files before building.

Comment: Maybe simple delete is better than modifying source files. Or rebuilding .rc files from command line.

Comment: @Digi, a simple `touch` to change the time stamp is much better than deleting, especially if something goes wrong.

Comment: +1, as an alternative to *touch.exe* you can use the [`batch file`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69581) to touch the resource file.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, though I'll probably take some time to write a specific tool that - lists .rc's from the .dpr - parses them and lists included files - checks wether any of these files has changed - if so touches the .rc

Comment: Nice idea Stijn. I hope you open source that little tool.